# How can I except some kind of errors on sass-lint?

Tags: css, sass, lint, except

I've been refactoring the CSS with sass on our project.
So I wanna fixing by the sass-lint, but it's so hard cause it have so many errors.
For example, 'Avoid using id selectors' or 'Selector 'mainFooter' should be written in lowercase with hyphens' like that.
These things can't be fixed now.

So I've found the document below, but they have only about 'BorderZero', 'StringQuotes' and 'all'.
https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#disabling-linters-via-source

How can I except my errors?
and where is the document about keywords list of sass-lint disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found it!
https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/config/default.yml

```
// scss-lint:disable IdSelector, SelectorFormat
```

Thanks :)